# SignalR (Version 1) hub connection to server during application pool recycle

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, signalr-hub

We have several servers running an ASP.NET Web API application. The Web API is accessed from a Windows desktop client application written in C#. The client uses a SignalR `HubConnection` object to start a reverse channel with the server through which it receives live feedback (log statements, status, etc.). Last year, one of our users reported that the client was periodically encountering the following error:

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

This error is received when the `HubConnection.Error` event is raised. I dug into the Windows Event Viewer logs on the server side and discovered that these errors coincided exactly with the occurrence of the following events:

> A process serving application pool 'ASP.NET v4.0' exceeded time limits during shut down. The process id was ‘xxxx'.

This event immediately followed 90 seconds after the application pool recycling event:

> A worker process with process id of ‘xxxx' serving application pool 'ASP.NET v4.0' has requested a recycle because the worker process reached its allowed processing time limit.

So clearly, the old worker process serving the ASP.NET v4.0 application pool was failing to shut down within the ShutdownTimeLimit of 90 seconds. I did some further experiments and discovered the following request was being retained in the request queue was causing the forced shutdown of the worker process:

[image: SignalR connect request]

The version of the SignalR libraries we were using at the time was 1.0.20228.0.

Last year, we upgraded to SignalR Version 2.2.31215.272 on both the client and server. It seems that this change resolved the problem I described above. The 'signalr/connect' request is still retained for the life of the hub connection, but when the application pool recycles the client and server gracefully reconnect it without any issues. Apparently some fix was made between SignalR V1 and V2 which allows it to handle application pool recycle events in a much more graceful manner.

Just for my own understanding, why was this issue being caused with V1 of the SignalR libraries, and what changed between V1 and V2 which resolved this issue?

Thanks.